# Azure Logic Apps - Do not zero-out value in record when value not avaliable

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an App that uses the Dynamics 365 CRM connector. My app can update the same record multiple times but include different data. I'm getting this data from an external API (UPS to be exact) and they don't always include the same information in each request.

This means that sometimes, I pass a `null` value to a field that previously had a value sent to it. This results in the value in the record being removed.

Below are the changes sent to the remote API via the connector. You can see that "estimateddelivery_v2" is `null`. This is because the value that corresponds to that Dynamic Content placeholder, is nonexistent. I am not providing the `null`.

```
{
  "dateshipped_v2": "2017-10-16",
  "delivereddate_v1": "2017-10-18",
  "estimateddelivery_v2": null,
  "parcelstatus": 100000001,
  "parcelstatusmodifiedon": "2017-10-19T08:45:21.9021362Z",
  "servicedescription_v1": "UPS GROUND",
  "shippingcarriers": 100000024
}
```

How do I avoid this? Should I provide the value as an empty string?

Comment: Is it an option to remove the fields having a null value before the update?

Comment: one option would be to get the record from CRM first, and then coalesce the values between what UPS returned and what is already stored in CRM.

Comment: @PieterVandenheede (Sorry. The notification took a long time to come to me.) Not in any maintainable way that I can think of. That's why I've come here.

Comment: @SzymonWylezol That's a good idea. I'll give it a try.